# SSIS Derived Column condition to replace null values based on a specific date

Tags: ssis, derived-column

I am working on a SSIS Package that will populate a SharePoint 2013 list with data from other SP lists.

I have created a Derived Column in the package, which is intended to replace null based on dates that are greater than or equal to a specific date in the data list. However, I am having trouble with the expression. Below is a condition and expression example that I am have trouble with.

```
REPLACENULL(ColumnName,"mm/dd/yyyy" > = GETDATE())
```

Any assistance to point out what I am doing wrong is appreciated.

Comment: You are comparing a string to a date. Replace your mm/dd/yyyy to a DATETIME.ParseExact("YOUR DATE", "YOUR FORMAT)

Comment: I was not able to get your suggestion to work properly, so I revised the package, which created a new problem that I will post as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression:

```
((DT_DATE)"9-1-2016") >=  (DT_DATE)ColumnName ? NULL((DT_WSTR, 50)) : ColumnName
```

- Notice: `REPLACENULL` is not useful for you here. What `REPLACENULL` does is that it:

  > Returns the value of second expression parameter if the value of first expression parameter is NULL". (See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/replacenull-ssis-expression))

You don't want to replace `NULL`, you want `NULL`!

Comment: Understood. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @DavidF You are welcome. If it answers your question, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response to your suggestion. I just had the opportunity to get back on the project and try it. Unfortunately what you suggested does not work.

I have tried a variation of what you suggested, but it doesn’t work either. Below is my variation.
ISNULL([ColumnName]) >= (DT_WSTR)"9/1/2016" 

Do you have any additional suggestions that I can try?

Comment: OK, you sad: "is intended to replace null based on dates that are greater than or equal to a specific DATE". I have 3 questions: 1. What is this specific DATE?  2. What is the your desired datatype of the derived column? 3. What is the error you get when you try my solution?

Comment: From an earlier comment, I understood that I should not use ISNULL and not REPLACENULL..

The specific date is 9-1-2016 and the data type from the server is DT_WSTR.

Thanks

Comment: @DavidF I updated my answer. Please check it and let me know if there are issues.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for `REPLACENULL` is `REPLACENULL(expression 1,expression 2)` where

expression 1 : 
The result of this expression is checked against NULL.

expression 2 :
The result of this expression is returned if the first expression evaluates to NULL.

If you're trying to REPLACE NULL values of a column based on another column's datetime condition, try something like this :

```
[column_1] >= GETDATE() ? REPLACENULL([column_2],"desired value") : [column_2]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.